# Rename User Control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created User control named MUSD.ASCX
And I changed the name of code-behind class to ctlAllBranchRouteMUSD.
When I try to use it, the IDE thinks that it doesn't exist and the reference doesn't have any impact in codes

faced with a similar problem recently, since I couldn't work with a designer file, I had to reopen the same solution in VS 2017 to complete the change in aspx file.

Comment: Instead of renaming it i suggest that you create a new ascx file and copy the code into there.

Comment: Check if the corresponding .designer.cs is updated properly or not

Comment: @Praveen : Designer Class is updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of renaming it i suggest that you create a new ascx file and copy the code into there.

However if you rename it you need to change the following files

- *.ascx
- *.ascx.cs
- *.ascx.designer.cs (this one is supposed to update automatically)

***.ascx:**

from

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="A.ascx.cs" Inherits="ObscriptSearch.A" %>
```

to

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="B.ascx.cs" Inherits="ObscriptSearch.B" %>
```

***.ascx.cs:**

from

```
 public partial class A: System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

to

```
 public partial class B: System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

***ascx.designer.cs:**

from

```
public partial class A
```

to

```
 public partial class B
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You edited both the filename and class in code? If not, try to change.
2. Be aware you changed also the extension, might be a problem :)

Comment: Hey Stefana, check this page out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer